# In Access 97, whats the quickest, surefire way to reveal and open the Tools->References window?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-97

I'm writing some instructions on how to remove missing references that the later versions of Access do not tolerate when migrating from 97 to 2007 for instance.

Right now I can reveal the references window by opening a code window by clicking on a module, but this access sheet has no modules. I want to get the power-user to the references window without creating a module, and without having them poke through the different forms to find the code behind for an event handler.

Is there a shortcut key to get to this window, or to enable it? Or a safe way to click there?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the complete list of shortcut keys. If it helps... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I press Ctrl+G, then the debug window appears, revealing the Tools menu option.

Thanks Mark for the comprehensive list of shortcut keys!